# Power consumption of a core with two hardware threads

Tags: cpu, core, multi-threaded

If a core has two hardware threads, will the core consume the same power in the following two scenarios:
a) only one thread is busy, the other is idle
b) both threads are busy

As far as I know, the voltage regulators in modern processors are per core, not per hardware thread, therefore is my above assumption correct?

Comment: Terminology nitpick:  Cores do not "have threads". A core with hyperthreading enabled is able to _run_ two threads at the same time. Threads are things created by and exist within processes in the OS; they are not parts of nor attributes of a core. In fact the CPU has no real concept of anything like "threads" or even "processes" at all. It has many mechanisms that are used by OSs to implement processes and threads, that's all.

Comment: @davidgo I found a very interesting bit in the Intel SDM that explains how Linux can show different clock speeds for the different LPs! Want details?

Answer (score 1):

"It depends" is about as good as we can probably get.

There is a lot of complicated logic and power gating going on and the power draw depends a lot  more on the actual tasks being done than how many threads there are. Having a single thread that contains a diverse and varied set of instructions that use all the CPU execution units could end up using more power than two threads that are contending for the same CPU resources.

For power efficiency unused sections of the CPU *could* be put into a low energy state is if the instruction dispatcher knows that there it is unlikely to be used for some time. Whether this happens would depend on the processor and require careful reading of processor documentation.

CPU design is also constantly changing and improving so what might be true today could change tomorrow.

Comment: In researching this I found an interesting tidbit in the Intel SDM. Each logical processor, as far as a system programmer is concerned, seems to have its own clock modulation MSR. But if these are set to  two different values for the two LPs in a core, they both run at the higher %age duty cycle! Regardless of what the OS thinks. Intel64/IA-32 SDM, 8.7.13.3: _"the modulation duty cycle must be set to the same value [for all LPs in a core]. If the duty cycle values differ between the LPs, the processor clock will be modulated at the highest duty cycle."_